# How to change color dynamically in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to change dynamically between two colors when pressing a button?

```
Example: 
Press button = yellow
Press button = red
Press button = yellow
Press button = red
...



$('button').click(function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'yellow');
    ...
});
```

Comment: toggle a class, easiest solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to hold the state, either by applying a class or holding the clicked state in a variable.

```js
$("button").on("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("red yellow");
});
```

```css
.red { background-color: red; }
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="red">click</button>
```

or just one class

```js
$("button").on("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("yellow");
});
```

```css
button { background-color: red; }
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
```

If you really want to use .css() than you need to hold a variable with the state

```js
(function () {

  var state = false;
  $("button").on("click", function () {
      state = !state;
      $(this).css("backgroundColor", state ? "red" : "yellow");
  }).trigger("click");
  
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe. Basically you are setting a variable that is the current color. And every time you click it switches the color. **IF** the starting color is red then you have the change the line from `var yellowon = true;` to `var yellowon = false;`

```
var yellowon = true;
$('button').click(function(){
    if (yellowon) {
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
        yellowon = false;
    }
    else {
        $(this).css('color', 'yellow');
        yellowon = true;
    }
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The colors in css are returned in a `rgb` format.
You can use this example in order to do the change:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  if ($(this).css('color') == 'rgb(255, 255, 0)') {
    $(this).css('color', 'rgb(255, 0, 0)');
  } else {
    $(this).css('color', 'rgb(255, 255, 0)');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="color: rgb(255, 255, 0)">Text</button>
```

Comment: That toggles between blue and yellow. Not red and yellow like asked in the question. :)

Comment: you are correct. thanks :) several changes in the question and I didn't think the color was so important ;)